# Error is shown in function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What is causing an error in my code below:

```
public void SetOperationDropDown() 
{ 
    if(CmbOperations.Items.Count == 0) 
    { 
        //ByDefault the selected text in the cmbOperations will be -SELECT OPERATIONS-. 

        cmbOperations.SelectedItem = "-SELECT OPERATIONS-";  

        //This is for adding four operations with value in operation dropdown  
        cmbOperations.Items.Insert(0, "PrimaryKeyTables");  
        cmbOperations.Items.Insert(1, "NonPrimaryKeyTables");  
        cmbOperations.Items.Insert(2, "ForeignKeyTables");  
        cmbOperations.Items.Insert(3, "NonForeignKeyTables");  
        cmbOperations.Items.Insert(4, "UPPERCASEDTables");  
        cmbOperations.Items.Insert(5, "lowercasedtables");  
    } 
    else 
    { 
        int? cbSelectedValue = null; 

        //OP ERROR SHOWN HERE
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbOperations.SelectedValue))

        cbSelectedValue = convert.toInt32(cmbOperations.SelectedValue); 
    } 

    //load your combo again 

    //OP ERROR SHOWN HERE
    if(cbSelectedValue != null) 

    cmbOperations.SelectedValue = cbSelectedValue.ToString(); 
}
```

(The error occurs specifically in this snippet of code:
`cbSelectedValue.ToString();`)

Comment: would be good to know what exactly is the error that is shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SelectedValue is an object, not a string.  So you need to convert it to a string:

```
if(cmbOperations.SelectedValue != null && !cmbOperations.SelectedValue.ToString() == string.Empty)
```